# Build a road network out of shapefile coordinates

Tags: java

I want to build a road network from the ESRI shapefiles. I am able to read the data from the .shp files but unable to proceed any further with building the road network out of the shapefile coordinates and display it on the screen. I am not that expirienced in Java. I would appreciate any kind of suggestions on how should i proceed now.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11509483/194609

Answer (score 0):

According to its [FAQ](http://openmap.bbn.com/cgi-bin/faqw.py), [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) supports ESRI Shapefiles. In particular, ["To display your data, look through the layer packages to see if your data type is handled by an existing layer."](http://openmap.bbn.com/cgi-bin/faqw.py?req=show&file=faq02.001.htp)